# Get a list of properties has been changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is an example function of `UpdateTotals`.

```
function updateTotals(data) {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    let totalTax = 0;

    data.Items.forEach(item => {
        const qty = parseInt(item.Qty, 10);
        const price = parseFloat(item.Price);
        const tax = parseFloat(item.Tax);

        const totalExc = price * qty;
        const totalInc = (price * qty) + tax;

        item.TotalExc = totalExc.toFixed(2);
        item.TotalInc = totalInc.toFixed(2);

        grandTotal += totalInc;
        totalTax += tax;
    });

    data.Totals.GrandTotal = grandTotal.toFixed(2);
    data.Totals.TotalTax = totalTax.toFixed(2);

    return data;
}
```

This is just a few examples of properties has been recalculated the sum, such as:
`data.Items[x].TotalExc`, `data.Items[x].TotalInc` and `data.Totals.GrandTotal`

In reality, there are a lot more fields in the Items array and outside of of Items property.

How can I get a list of properties that have been updated (sums) so that I can pass the properties to the database (NoSQL for example) for update?

Comment: There isn't any baked in way to do this in JS. You'll need to keep track of state somehow and then perform a diffing operation after you have performed your computations.

Comment: what kind of track of state would look like for example and where would you store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is contrived, but something like this...

```
const foo = {
  type: "fruit",
  name: "apple",
  color: "red"
};

const bar = {
  type: "fruit",
  name: "banana",
  color: "yellow"
};

function findChangedProps(prev, current) {
  const changedProps = [];

  for (const prop in prev) {
    if (prev[prop] !== current[prop]) {
      changedProps.push(prop);
    }
  }

  return changedProps;

}

console.log(findChangedProps(foo, bar));
```

If you're using a library like React, it provides baked-in ways to do this, but if you're just using Vanilla JS there isn't an API for this AFAIK.

---- Update ----

Some Co-workers told me about the new [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) API which I was unaware of. This allows your function to create a proxy object that you update.

```
var changedProps = [];

var foo = {
  type: "apple",
  color: "red"
};

var catcher = {
  set: function(obj, prop) {
    changedProps.push(prop);
    return Reflect.set(...arguments);
  }
};

var p = new Proxy(foo, catcher);

console.log("p before mutation", p);

p.color = "yellow";

console.log("p after mutation", p);

console.log("foo recieves mutation too", foo);

console.log("changedProps", changedProps);
```

Comment: Proxies have been around for years now (from ES6), so I'm not sure you can call it "new". But they are clearly underrated.

Comment: Well it was "new" to me I suppose. Glad you hopped on to clarify.